# Remove undefined select option after $compile?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

It appears that when you create a select element inside of a directive, it creates a sort of dummy option (I assume since at this point it doesn't know what to set it to and doesn't want to make assumptions). The top option below is the option I mean:

```
<select ng-model="optionVal">
    <option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>
    <option value="opt1">Option One</option>
    <option value="opt2">Option Two</option>
</select>
```

Functionally everything works, but having that empty entry in the select box is ugly, and I'd like to remove it. Does anyone know a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

That option is created because your model does not contain one of `opt1` or `opt2`, so it creates an option to match the current value of your model. The way to avoid that is to set your model to a value first.

Comment: Thanks Dale, I also tried it with a placeholder option and tried to set that in the controller so that it would see it when it did the compile - it didn't work, but it sounds like it *should* work, so I likely just didn't implement it exactly correctly. This helps me, as it verifies that this is the right approach so I'll keep tinkering with it. Thanks!

Comment: Placeholder may not work either because it needs to be an object match not a string match, so for example if your options are { label: 'Option One', value:'opt1' } then your model needs to be assigned a similar object, which could be a placeholder object { label: 'Placeholder', value:'' } but then that will be created as a real option also.